# C# Desktop Applications?

Tags: c#, .net

In looking at the use of C# in a ISV setting, I'm wondering what prominent C# based desktop apps are out there? I can think of only Paint .NET.

Is C# a good idea for an ISV, or should one stick to more native environments like Delphi or even QT?

Of course any experienced based advise or feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, C# can be used quite effectivly to build applications.  In regards what  applciations are out there, what are you looking for?  Big apps, little apps?

I know of a big app that is built on the .NET framework (unsure if C# or VB) and that is Quickbooks.

Comment: Quickbooks is pretty well known.

Answer (score 7):

Developing a Desktop applications in C# is great. Its not just for Web Apps.

WinForms are going to save you huge amounts of time. It really is a first class citizen when it comes to desktop windows development. If interop is a problem you can always use  P/Invoke and COM object wrapping that VS does for you.

Done right, it will be a breeze to maintain and update when the client changes their mind on what they want.

Yes, the framework needs to be on the machine, But this shouldn't be a problem if they have ever used windows update. Nowadays what language doesn't come with a run time library. In VS you can create simple installers that include the runtime.

Of course if your gonna deploy to Linux and mono, your mileage may very.

Answer (score 5):

[PlasticSCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/)

Comment: The greatest version control system ever!! try it !!

Answer (score 4):

If you can control the system requirements for your application, C# is fine. Some end users still (even though we're nearly in 2009 now) object to a 40MB runtime for some reason, so if you're looking to deploy an application commercially, that may be an issue for you. In a corporate setting, though, where there is some standardization of software on users' computers, this is probably not a problem.

Delphi and QT specifically are both problems. Delphi is effectively a dead language. Companies that are using it these days are, for the most part, porting their code away from it as fast as they can (job boards seem to be full of Delphi-to-C# migration jobs these days). You may like QT, but that moves almost as slowly as Delphi in the Windows world, so I would never consider it to be a real option.

Comment: Delphi is more popular than Ruby in TIOBE's top 10 index. Are you saying ruby is a dead language also? Delphi is just dead in the US, it's very much alive everywhere else. And 40 MB is big if you host centrally on a file-share.

Comment: Why would you assume the only options are "dead" and "not dead?" Ruby's not a dead language; it's a new language (by comparison). My point about 40MB was that if you're in a corporate environment, you have the ability to standardize software ON USER MACHINES, and the size is irrelevant.

Comment: The biggest telecom company in my country uses standardized desktops, but does not include most software on the machines because the configuration follows the profile, not the machine. Our software runs from a file-share on their network.

Comment: I think that's a little different. .NET is not software that you run; it's something that has to be installed on the machine. Anyway, I WAS talking about consumer dislike of installing a runtime, not questionable corporate setups.

Answer (score 4):

More:

- Business Plan Pro
- Rescue Time client
- Sony Vegas
- Sql Management Studio
- VS 2010 (much more so than VS 200x)
- NASA's World Wind
- BabySmash
- Windows Live Writer
- Microsoft Office Accounting
- Fiddler 2
- Windows Mobile Device Center
- AdiIRC
- Jetbrains dotTrace
- Lots of Lenovo utilities
- Planbook

These are just the ones installed on my PC...

Answer (score 3):

I think that Microsoft Expression Blend/Studio is written in C#

Comment: Yes it is :)   The next version of visual studio is all manged.  its new UI is written in WPF

Answer (score 3):

Anything done for Robotics Studio, any XNA game (quite a few commerical ones are coming out now)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you would not use C# as an ISV. The problem is ensuring that your target market has the .NET framework. If you are using 3.5, you can build a mini version into your distribution though this increases the file sizes for downloads of course.

Answer (score 3):

Some supplemental information to think about:

One of the typical points against doing desktop applications the distribution model is a lot more difficult to manage.  With web apps, if you have a large user base, you can do an update and instantly have your entire user base running on the latest version.

With traditional desktop apps, you'd have to send out an .msi or build something yourself.
However, with ClickOnce and the Updater Application Block (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978574.aspx), it's so easy to build intelligent updating into your application that it might play very nicely into an ISV plan.

Even though VS 2008/WPF is shrinking the gap, it's typically much faster to develop client applications in the WinForms space that on the web, so I think it's a very viable approach.

Answer (score 2):

I believe TimeSnapper is written in C#

Answer (score 2):

I have worked for an ISV before that used Delphi and it was excellent for their needs. It still produces great native applications and although dieing it is certainly not dead (yet). Until recently I would have recommened Delphi over c# for desktop applications as I had performance and footprint consderations but as .net can now be considered ubiquitous and that the platform is now maturing my opinoin would probably go with c# (over Delphi).
If you need to consider employees, you will find that there are fewer Delphi developers around that c# ones. So you may struggle to entice good devleopers in as you are using that.
That said Delphi is looking exciting again with the Delphi prism VS plugin.

Just as an aside did you know that the c# compiler is written in c++? Delphi was written in Delphi from v1.0

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Centre is powered by .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that MS use C# to build many of their apps both Windows and Web.  At this time, C# is a great language to go with because of the flexibility of the language/framework.

Answer (score 0):

Who are your target users? Their needs will dictate your choice of language. C# and VB.NET  are good general purpose langs, but if you are targeting Mac or *nix, you may want something like C++.

Comment: windows, currently I develop Cocoa apps.

Answer (score 0):

The zune software (v2 and up) is written in c#. Oh, and Sage Timberline Office is written in .net (mostly).

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a developer tool, the excellent open source IDE [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) was built in C#. I've also worked on another which (despite being semi-commercially-available) I'm not at liberty to divulge. (Very vertical market.)

I'm a huge fan of the C#/WinForms combination, and can't see why you wouldn't go that route if your developers are already familiar with C# and you want to get into the desktop space.

Answer (score 0):

A very prominent example for a commercialy successful application would be Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 itself.
If you are looking into building a client or server application for the Windows ecosystem .Net with C# is an absolut valid choice. You'll get a very rich framework, a great third-party-app ecosystem and a huge community.
If you need a minimal memory footprint for your application or are very hardware centric then C++ maybe an option.
If you want to target the UNIX/LINUX or Apple platforms you should be looking in frameworks more native for the respective platform, though you can get a certain degree of interoperability with the Mono project (But I am not up to date on how complete their implementation of .Net currently is).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the matrox graphics card configuration utilities are using the .net-framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still just a student, but for what it's worth (and from other answers preceding mine), there seem to be quite a few apps in C#.

I'd advise working through the book Head First C# ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514824)).  This book will give you a pretty solid idea of what you can do with the language.

=-MDP-=

Answer (score 0):

[Creative Docs .NET](http://www.creativedocs.net) is a very nice example of C# application.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's World Wide Telescope software is written in c#

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to get started quickly, I recently published [DesktopBootstrap](https://github.com/adamsmith/DesktopBootstrap), which is my attempt to factor out the elements you'll need to get started.

Hope that helps!