# Android companion desktop application

Tags: android, windows, desktop

I want to create a companion Windows desktop program for my app.  One that would sync the database on the phone with the desktop application and have a UI for manipulating the data.

Problem is, I have never built a desktop program and don't know how.  I needed some direction in terms of the language to program it in (is it C++?).  The application would read/write to a database and have a customized UI.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Edit: The computer this is running on, for industry security reasons, cannot install Java or any other third party software.  It would need to run out of the box, install the exe and should run on any windows version.

Thanks,

Comment: That is an extremely subjective question, kind of like asking "What should I use to build a house?", use the right tool for the right job and that you're comfortable with it. There's http://androidcommander.com/ that does exactly that for Android handsets. Here's another hosted on codeplex - http://de.codeplex.com/

Comment: Oh wait...something's not quite right there - clarify "*or any other third party software*"... Android Commander/Droid Explorer which is a Windows companion suite specifically for Android, that's third party, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution after researching, and thanks for the replies, is to build it using Visual C++ and MFC (Microsoft Foundation Class).  That will create a native application that does not have environmental dependencies (like .NET or JRE).  It will require the MFC dll files to be included with the program, however, that is not an issue as at it can be embedded into the application.

FYI I do believe embedding the MFC dll flies (static linking) is not recommended for typical applications, however, this is a very specialized program.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with Java... it's the same language of Android, you have everything you need to build desktop applications, and it's plattform independent. For the grafic interface you could use Swing / AWT.

Edit: If you can't use Java, c++ would be a way to go. But you could also try C#, it's very close to Java and "managed" (you don't have to care about garbage collection, for example). Visual basic is also an alternative but somewhat limited. See this thread for C# [C# Desktop Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209069/c-sharp-desktop-applications)

I would only use c++ if the application has critic speed requirements. Like a game or similar.   Or some other certain, special reason, which you don't seem to have.

Comment: Thank your for responding quickly.I should have mentioned, that the computer that this is going onto does not have java, and for security reasons in the industry java cannot be installed on the computer.  Is there a language that can run natively on windows out of the box if you know what i mean?

Comment: uhm, well, if it's only windows and it has to be "native" c++ would be a way to go. But you could also try c#, it's more to Java and "managed" (you don't have to care about garbage collection, for example). Visual basic is also an alternative but somewhat limited.

Comment: The OP clearly indicated zero knowledge of windows development, and even if went ahead and decided to learn and develop the software, native or managed - brilliant! *BUT* that constitutes third-party software. The op is putting themselves in a position where that PC "cannot run java or third-party software"..which contradicts the nature of the OP's question... *industry security reasons...* hence my comment above saying that something's not quite right there...

Comment: thank you, you were very helpful even if I wasn't able to explain myself completely.  I hope some of the other users learn from that.

Answer (score 0):

The "native" language of Windows is C/C++, but it's not the easiest one to master. For someone with a Java experience, may I recommend Visual Basic. It's garbage-collected like Java. The syntax is rather different though.

Note that VB.NET and VB proper are rather different. The former requires a copy of the .NET environment.

There is a DLL you have to install to run VB programs - VBRUNxxx.DLL, where xxx is the version. So it's not like there are no runtime requirements at all. If that's still a deal breaker, then go with C++, and make sure to specify the non-DLL version of the runtime in the build settings (with VB this is not an option).